# DBContext conversion from ObjectContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-4.5, entity-framework-5

I'm use this function in EntityFramework 4.0 (ObjectContext). Now i'm using EF 5.0. My problem is `DefaultContainerName`,`GetObjectByKey` methods not found in `DBContext`

```
public static T GetObjectByID<T>(int ID, string tableName = "")
        {
            var localDB = new LocalBaseEntities();

            string entitySetName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", localDB.DefaultContainerName, string.IsNullOrEmpty(tableName) ? typeof(T).Name + "s" : tableName);

            try
            {
                IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, object>> entityKeyValues =
                new KeyValuePair<string, object>[] { new KeyValuePair<string, object>(typeof(T).Name + "ID", ID) };
                EntityKey key = new System.Data.EntityKey(entitySetName, entityKeyValues);            
                return (T)localDB.GetObjectByKey(key);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }            

            return default(T);
        }
```

How to convert this function?

Or how to make function like this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`DbContext` is an adapter (wrapper) over `ObjectContext`. Also it implements explicitly interface `IObjectContextAdapter`. Cast you dbContext to this interface type and wrapped `ObjectContext` instance will be available:

```
ObjectContext context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbContext).ObjectContext;
```

*BTW* new class `DbSet<T>` has method `Find` which also searches entities by key. So, it seems all your code now will look like

```
T entity = dbContext.Set<T>().Find(id);
```